# Facebook sdk, Android dependencies showing facebooksdk.jar is missing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

[image]

I have downloaded facebook sdk from facebook developers site,but all the samples given in the sdk are showing the error 
  facebooksdk.jar is missing in facebook\bin,but I found only facebook.apk in this \bin folder.
I just like to know why I am getting this error.How can I solve this issue?

Please refer to the image which is attached below. Please suggest for the solution .

Comment: you should import FacebookSDK library project in your workspace and then include that library project in your project.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and as I imported FacebookSDK project and all sample projects with it as described in this getting started https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started . Due to this none of the projects compiled as samples depends on facebooksdk.jar and FacebookSDK project doesn't build because of error sin other projects. Do this:

1. Close all the sample projects
2. Just clean and built FacebookSDK project
3. You should see facebooksdk.jar in bin folder
4. Open all the other projects, clean and build

All errors regarding the missing library should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the FacebookSDK is marked as a library. Go to its Properties | Android, check is "Is Library" is checked.
This somehow got unchecked when I was recovering from an Eclipse crash.